# SqlBase and Gupta windows to the sky

Tags: sqlbase, guptateamdeveloper

Anybody who can advise or have experience on the possibility to have an SqlBase database in a cloud environment and run a Gupta application which is stored on local PCs?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We have some experience running a SQL-Database (Oracle, SqlServer, SqlBase) on a remote Server connected over WAN. Most often data access is very slow and you have to write your application carefully.

The reason for the slowness is usually not the bandwidth but the number of hops an IP-packet takes. Each hop adds some milliseconds of delay which oftens sums up to a painful experience. So it's ok to get one big blob from a database. It's also ok to fetch large resultsets. But when there are a lot of smaller queries it will get very slow.

There are two solutions to this problem:

1) Use a dedicated line from client to server if possible.

2) Write your application in a way that minimizes the number of queries.